# destructuring with the same keys in JavaScrypt

Tags: javascript

I can get to limitfrom in the second case if I rename limitfrom to limitfrom2, but I don't understand how to get to the value without renaming the key. Maybe I'm doing the wrong thing about the destructuring itself.

create an object

```
const vedPlus = {
transferLegal: {
    stageOne: {
        limitfrom: 0,
        limitUpTo: 60,
        commission: 0
    },
    stageTwo: {
        limitfrom2: 60,
        limitUpTo2: 1000,
        commission2: 29
    },
}
```

then I do the destructuring in 4 steps.

```
const {transferLegal} = vedPlus

const {stageOne, stageTwo} = transferLegal

const {limitfrom, limitUpTo, commission} = stageOne

const {limitfrom2, limitUpTo2, commission2} = stageTwo
```

Create a function

```
function calc (i) {
if (i >= limitfrom && i <= limitUpTo) {
    return i * commission
} else if (i >= limitfrom2 && i <= limitUpTo2) {
    return i * commission2
} else {
    console.log('error')
}
```

result

```
const price = 71
console.log(calc(price))
```

Is there a way to get to the value without renaming the key?

Comment: you may want to use `const limitfrom = stage['limitfrom'] || stage['limitfrom2']` to get the value of property=`limitfrom or limitfrom2`  from stageOne or stageTwo object.

Comment: You can use aliases when destructuring: const{limitfrom: a, limitUpTo: b, commission: c} = stageTwo

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same property names for both inner objects, and then assign new unique names when destructuring to prevent conflicts, using `const { prop: newName } = source` syntax.

It may not produce the most readable code, but at least it can be done.

**Demo:**

```js
const vedPlus = {
  transferLegal: {
    stageOne: { limitfrom: 0, limitUpTo: 60, commission: 0 },
    stageTwo: { limitfrom: 60, limitUpTo: 1000, commission: 29 },
  }
}

const { transferLegal } = vedPlus;
const { stageOne, stageTwo } = transferLegal;
const { limitfrom, limitUpTo, commission } = stageOne;
const { limitfrom: limitfrom2, limitUpTo: limitUpTo2, commission: commission2 } = stageTwo;

console.log(limitfrom, limitUpTo, commission);
console.log(limitfrom2, limitUpTo2, commission2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  But certainly not like this:

```
const {limitfrom, limitUpTo, commission} = stageOne;
const {limitfrom, limitUpTo, commission} = stageTwo;
```

Because you'd be re-declaring the same variables in the same scope.  After these two lines, if you were to refer to the variable `limitfrom`, which one would you expect it to be and why?

If the keys have the same name, that's fine as long as they are unique within their context.  In this case within their individual objects.  You can use those objects to reference them:

```
const {stageOne, stageTwo} = transferLegal;

//...

if (i >= stageOne.limitfrom && i <= stageOne.limitUpTo) {
  return i * stageOne.commission
} else if (i >= stageTwo.limitfrom && i <= stageTwo.limitUpTo) {
  return i * stageTwo.commission
}
```

Basically, *absolutely everything* doesn't have to be destructured into its own variable with a single value.  Objects exist for a reason, use them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the data (vedPlus) as the same structure you can do the renaming while you are destructuring

```js
const vedPlus = {
    transferLegal: {
        stageOne: {
            limitfrom: 0,
            limitUpTo: 60,
            commission: 0
        },
        stageTwo: {
            limitfrom: 60,
            limitUpTo: 1000,
            commission: 29
        }
    }
}

const {
    transferLegal: {
        stageOne: {
            limitfrom,
            limitUpTo,
            commission
        },
        stageTwo: {
            limitfrom: limitfrom2,
            limitUpTo: limitUpTo2,
            commission: commission2
        }
    }
} = vedPlus

function calc(i) {
    if (i >= limitfrom && i <= limitUpTo) {
        return i * commission
    } else if (i >= limitfrom2 && i <= limitUpTo2) {
        return i * commission2
    } else {
        console.log('error')
    }
}

const price = 71

console.log(calc(price))
```

Answer (score 0):

if the final goal is a simple calculation, then the use of the destructuring mechanism does not bring anything useful

```js
const vedPlus = 
  { transferLegal: 
    { stageOne: { limitfrom: 0,  limitUpTo: 60,   commission: 0  } 
    , stageTwo: { limitfrom: 60, limitUpTo: 1000, commission: 29 } 
  } }

function calc(i)
  {
  let obj = vedPlus.transferLegal
  for (let stage in obj)
    {
    if (obj[stage].limitfrom <= i && i <= obj[stage].limitUpTo) 
      return obj[stage].commission *i
    }
  throw `error: ${i} is out of range!`
  }

console.log( '50 =>', calc(50) )
console.log( '500 =>', calc(500) )
console.log( '5000 =>', calc(5000) )
```